# Application NightTime Mode

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uicolor

I have just finished creating my first application and would like to add some additional customisations to it. That is, in my `settingsViewController` I have added a switch which allows to set the colours to a nighttime mode. My questions is how can I actually get my application to do this.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect this thing to be handled by iOS itself because its an app feature that you will have to implement.

You can change background colors to dark and all those `UILabel` `UIButton` `UITextView` dark colored as well to have a feature called dark mode(Dark theme) upon user selection.